# Generate PDF automatically and automatically upload to server

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, pdf, pdf-generation

I am working on improving a daily tasks which could be sped up if what I need exists. It could save me about 2 hours of work a day if it can be done. My current way of generating reports is long. Here is my current flow.

1. I click generate report and the report is automatically generated using PHP, CSS, & HTML.
2. I work on a Mac, so in order to save the report as a PDF, I click on "print". The print window appears and I then click on "Save As PDF".
3. I save this report to my desktop. I then upload it to my server.

The 3 steps above is my current process. What I would like to be able to do is this:

1. I click generate report and the report is automatically generated using PHP, CSS, & HTML.
2. If the report looks good, I click on "save". The save button will automatically generate a PDF and will upload it to my server.

Is this possible? If so, can someone point me in the right direction. I prefer to do this with PHP, but if there's another way I can do this, that is fine as well.

Comment: @nyarlathotep, I really have no idea what you mean.

Comment: my mistake, didn't read that properly that there's manual intervention anyway. What actually takes so long in your current process? Only automating step 2 and 3 seem to be the question - printing a pdf and uploading it can't take 2 hours???

Comment: When I have to do this over 300 times a day 2 extra steps make a big difference lol. I left a couple of other steps out because they are irrelevant to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to learn how to do this, *and well*, there are great resources available to you.

In fact, [Welling/Thomson's PHP and MySQL Web Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329166) has two chapters that are perfect you. Chapter 19 deals with files and Chapter 32 is entitled "Generating Personalized PDF Documents." I recommend you give it a thorough read.

If you encounter problems along the way, then you should come back here and post them in discrete components.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. An I am not looking for code. That is why I said this in my last paragraph, "Is this possible? If so, can someone point me in the right direction. I prefer to do tis with PHP, but if another can do this, that is fine as well."

Comment: Sure. Just wanted to clarify. It is indeed possible, and that book will teach you how to do it and how to do it well.

Answer (score 0):

you could use MPDF, a great tool to generate pdfs.
check: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/ download the pack and check the examples. :D sorry about the english

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't have a built-in PDF generator, although there are libraries you can add that will do it. Creating the PDF by outputting the correct formatting is non-trivial.

Instead, you can use an HTML to PDF converter - I've used them on Linux, such as `wkhtmltopdf`, so they should work okay on a Mac, too. You would just generate the report as normal, but output it to a file rather than the browser. Then run the converter on the HTML and presto, a PDF version.